# Are there any good statistical inference exercise and solutions books?

Tags: statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I was wondering if anyone was aware of any exercise and solutions books on statistical inference at a graduate level (ie, UMVUE, UMP tests, hypothesis testing) that contains nothing but exercises and solutions? I would like to do a look of problems to strengthen my understanding of inference and am interested in finding a book that is similar to [1000 Exercises in Probability by Grimmett and Stirzaker](https://books.google.com/books/about/One_Thousand_Exercises_in_Probability.html?id=SQqTo8cwx1QC). In this book, they have over 1000 exercises with corresponding solutions. Thanks in advance for the recommendations!